# How to fire function when user selected item from ul element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have this Html code:

```
<ul id="cultureMenu" class="top-links list-inline" onselect="">
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle no-text-underline" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src=@flag width="16" height="11" alt="lang" />@Resources.Resources.Language</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-langs dropdown-menu">
            <li><a value="he" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="~/assets/images/flags/no.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" />Norsk</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a value="en" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/us.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> ENGLISH</a></li>
            <li><a value="de" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/de.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> Deutsch</a></li>
            <li><a value="ru" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/ru.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> Русский </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to fire function when item(`li`) selected by user.

I have this implementation on jQuery:

```
        //function fired when user change culture
        (function ($) {
            $('#cultureMenu ul li').click(function () {
              alert("item selected");
            })
        })(jQuery);
```

but I need to implement it on pure JavaScript.

How can  I implement above logic in pure Javascript?

Comment: add onclick to the element in the html

Comment: usually when you start to learn a programing language you start from the basics not with a framework  the internet is full of examples

Comment: what have you tired, what errors do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick solution you can use onclick on each element, bear in mind that for a huge number of elements this is not a maintanable option and you should create the handler apart.

```
<ul id="cultureMenu" class="top-links list-inline" onselect="">
<li>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle no-text-underline" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src=@flag width="16" height="11" alt="lang" />@Resources.Resources.Language</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-langs dropdown-menu">
        <li onclick="yourfunction(this)"><a value="he" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="~/assets/images/flags/no.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" />Norsk</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li onclick="yourfunction(this)"><a value="en" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/us.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> ENGLISH</a></li>
        <li onclick="yourfunction(this)"><a value="de" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/de.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> Deutsch</a></li>
        <li  onclick="yourfunction(this)"><a value="ru" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/ru.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> Русский </a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

then declare your function

```
function yourfunction(item){
   alert(item.querySelector('a').getAttribute('value') + " selected");
}
```

Comment: Suggesting inline click handler is going backwards

Comment: Of course it is not scalable, this is just a quick solution for a couple of elements. If the number of elements in the list is being loaded from a db or it is longer, do not include the onclick...

Comment: Thanks for the post. Any idea how can I get value of the selected li element in yourfunction() ?

Comment: @Michael, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Michael I've edited the answer, try passing this as the parameter

Answer (score 1):

You should bind a `click` event handler for every `li` DOM element.

You can use `querySelectorAll` in order to find out all `li` elements from your unordered `list`.

```js
var lis=document.querySelectorAll('#cultureMenu ul li');
for(i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
  lis[i].onclick=function(){
     console.log(this.querySelector('a').getAttribute('value'));
     console.log(this.querySelector('a').textContent.trim());
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="cultureMenu" class="top-links list-inline" onselect="">
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle no-text-underline" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src=@flag width="16" height="11" alt="lang" />@Resources.Resources.Language</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-langs dropdown-menu">
            <li><a value="he" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="~/assets/images/flags/no.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" />Norsk</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a value="en" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/us.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> ENGLISH</a></li>
            <li><a value="de" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/de.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> Deutsch</a></li>
            <li><a value="ru" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/ru.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> Русский </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for post.But I need pure javascript.And I see you have link to jquery library

Comment: @Michael, it was only a mistake.I don't use it.